# How do I display Net::SFTP timestamps in a different time zone?

Tags: perl, timezone

I am using [Net::SFTP](http://p3rl.org/Net%3a%3aSFTP). My intention is to list the files along with their modified date. I am able to list the files with date in UTC format. I need in the EDT format. Is there any setting available?

Presently, I am using Perl 5 on Linux.

```
my $sftp = Net::SFTP->new($host, %args) or die "Cannot connect to $@";
$sftp->ls('.' , sub { print $_[0]->{longname}, "\n" });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, longName field of the listing is server-rendered and obsolete / not recommended for use. SFTP provides a structure with data for each directory entry, and times are listed there in UTC.

From documentation:

> If $subref is specified, for each entry in the directory, $subref will be called and given a reference to a hash with three keys: filename, the name of the entry in the directory listing; *longname*, an entry in a "long" listing like ls -l; and *a*, a Net::SFTP::Attributes object, which contains the file attributes of the entry (atime, mtime, permissions, etc.).

So you need to get those *a* object and use its *atime* and *mtime* fields. Once you have them, converting them to local time zone should be trivial if you need a fixed timezone.